# Mysql Trigger updating other table after insert on current table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mariadb

I have two tables. One is called "borrowed" and the other is called "devices". I have a field in the table Devices which is set to 0 by default. I want when an entry in the table "borrowed" to be added. That the entry in the table "Devices" is set to 1 by a trigger. Exactly where the table ID "borrowed" = the table ID is "Devices".

My idea to realize that was this:

```
BEGIN

   UPDATE `devices` 

    SET devices.borrowed = "1"

    WHERE devices.id = borrowed.id

    LIMIT 1;
END
```

Or

```
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `test`;CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `test` AFTER INSERT ON `borrowed` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN UPDATE `devices` SET devices.borrowed = 1 WHERE devices.id = borrowed.id LIMIT 1; END
```

My result is that all records are set to 1 and not just the one with the same serial number. With the LIMIT command he only sets 1 to the right value but the device with the wrong serial number is set to 1.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Does the table ever have more than one row?  `LIMIT 1` without an `ORDER BY` may pick a row unpredictably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing you are using MySQL and you want something like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_borrowed_insert AFTER INSERT ON borrowed
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE devices
       SET devices.borrowed = 1
       WHERE devices.id = new.id;
END;
```

I don't think triggers are a good way to implement such logic.  A foreign key relationship and `JOIN` should be fine to figure out which devices are borrowed.  If you need a trigger for the `insert`, you also need one for `delete` and `update`.